# Customize the login screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-custom-view

How was this personalization or effect possible?

Have a background screen with a part of the screen with degrade or solid color.

[image]

[image]

I tried to do with the gradient shape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#c53766"
        android:endColor="#8149aa"
        android:angle="135"></gradient>
</shape>
```

How could you do this customization of the login screen according to the sample image.
Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try Diagonal layout add dependency

```
compile 'com.github.florent37:diagonallayout:1.0.7'
```

and use below code

```
<com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        app:diagonal_angle="20"
        app:diagonal_position="top"
        app:diagonal_direction="right">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/mountains" />

</com.github.florent37.diagonallayout.DiagonalLayout>
```

for more details check [this link](https://github.com/florent37/DiagonalLayout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use adobexD which is fairly simple to use and made for user interface. There are several tutorials available.
And after you create your screen with the gradient you want, you can export it and simply use a android:background with the screen